# Do I have to supply both index.js and index.d.ts?

Tags: typescript, npm

I have this common module written entirely in typescript, to be shared between two ionic app projects. It's in a working state now, but I have had to put this same content in both index.js and index.d.ts:

```
export * from './dist/domain/Product';
export * from './dist/services/ProductService';
```

If I don't put it in index.js, webpack doesn't include the module in the final app.

If I don't put it in index.d.ts, transpile fails on finding those names.

So my question is: is there any way to avoid manually maintaining both files and keep them in sync?

(A side question: is there any way to export by wildcard? Something like `export * from './dist/**/*'`?)

Comment: can you put that in `index.ts` and then generate both `index.js` and `index.d.ts` using `tsc` with `-d` flag (or `"declaration": true` in `tsconfig.json`)?

Comment: @artem Well that works. I had to set `"main": 'dist/index'` in package.json since now index.js is generated into 'dist'. Would you like to make your comment into an answer so I can mark it?  Thanks.